# Find required amount using target value and percentage

Tags: statistics

In my example, 2.85% of website traffic converts a sale. There are 50 items, how much traffic is required to covert 50 sales?

What is the formula?

Comment: Maybe the rule of three could be enough.

Comment: Let $n$ be the number website of traffic , Then the equation to sell one item is $n\cdot 0.0285=1$.  To sell 50 items you need (at least ) $50\cdot n$ number of website traffic.

Comment: What value would be the required traffic in this example?

Comment: $n=\frac{1}{0.0258}, 50n=\frac{50}{0.0258}$

Comment: @KyleUnderhill OK? Any reply is welcomed.

Comment: @callculus42 Yes that was the solution thanks

Comment: @KyleUnderhill You´re welcome.